# Excel or R - Create variable with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, excel

Two data sets:

Data1

**x  y  z**

A B **?**

C D **?**

Data2

**x1  y1  z1**

C    D   100

E    F   200

A    B   300

In excel preferably (or in R if necessary) I want to create variable "z" which =z1 if x=x1 and y=y1. So z would be {300, 100} in the above example.

Comment: In R , this should work for you `merge(Data1,Data2,by.x=c("x","y"),by.y=c("x1","y1"),all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create in each sheet a column m:

```
=A2&B2
```

Make sure m1 (C) comes before z1 (D).

Then use VLOOKUP to find the correct z for m

```
=VLOOKUP(D2;Data2!C:D;2;FALSE)
```

Data1:

```
x   y   z   m
A   B   300 AB
C   D   100 CD
```

Data2:

```
x1  y1  m1  z1
C   D   CD  100
E   F   EF  200
A   B   AB  300
```